# Objects that can be initialized but not assigned

Tags: c++, initialization, variable-assignment

I need to create a class whose objects can be initialized but not assigned.

I thought maybe I could do this by not defining the assignment operator, but the compiler uses the constructor to do the assignment.

I need it to be this way:

```
Object a=1;    // OK
a=1;           // Error
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can [delete](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Deleted_functions) the assignment operator:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Object
{
    Object(int) {}
    Object& operator=(int) = delete;
};

int main()
{
    Object a=1;    // OK
    a=1;           // Error
}
```

**Alternative Solution**

You can use the [explicit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit) keyword:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Object
{
    explicit Object(int) {}
};

int main()
{
    Object a(1);    // OK - Uses explicit constructor
    a=1;           // Error
}
```

**Update**

As mentioned by user2079303 in the comments:

> It might be worth mentioning that the alternative solution does not prevent regular copy/move assignment like `a=Object(1)`

This can be avoided by using: `Object& operator=(const Object&) = delete;`

Answer (score 62):

Making `a` **const** will do the trick

```
const Object a=1;    // OK
```

Now you won't be able to assign any value to `a` as `a` is declared as `const`. Note that if you declare `a` as `const`, it is necessary to initialize `a` at the time of declaration.

Once you have declared `a` as `const` and also initialized it, you won't be able to assign any other value to `a`

```
 a=1;   //error
```

Comment: +1 While the other answers address what the OP asked in their paragraph, my gut says this is what they actually *meant* to ask.

Comment: And if you want it to apply to all instances of `Object`, use `const` on one (or more) of the member variables.  Voila, assignment operator deleted by default.

Answer (score 13):

> I hoped this would be so by not defining the assignment operator

This doesn't work because the copy assignment operator (which takes `const Object&` as parameter) is implicitly generated. And when you write `a = 1`, the generated copy assignment operator will be tried to invoke, and `1` could be implicitly converted to `Object` via converting constructor `Object::Object(int)`; then `a = 1;` works fine.

You can declare the assignment operator taking `int` as [deleted](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Deleted_functions) (since C++11) explicitly; which will be selected prior to the copy assignment operator in overload resolution.

> If the function is overloaded, overload resolution takes place first, and the program is only ill-formed if the deleted function was selected.

e.g.

```
struct Object {
    Object(int) {}
    Object& operator=(int) = delete;
};
```

There're also some other solutions with side effects. You can declare `Object::Object(int)` as `explicit` to prohibit the implicit conversion from `int` to `Object` and then make `a = 1` fail. But note this will make `Object a = 1;` fail too because copy initialization doesn't consider `explicit` constructor. Or you can mark the copy assignment operator deleted too, but this will make the assignment between `Object`s fail too.

Comment: Before `=delete` we would declare it private and never define it.  Or use Boost’s handy mix-in.

Comment: I mean that before it was possible to declare a deleted function (available as of C++11), we would declare that function private instead.

Comment: I see, yes that's the pre-C++11 approach for it.

Answer (score 9):

> How can I do it?

#### Option 1:

Make the constructor `explicit`

```
struct Object
{
   explicit Object(int in) {}
};
```

#### Option 2:

`delete` the assignment operator.

```
struct Object
{
   Object(int in) {}
   Object& operator=(int in) = delete;
};
```

You can use both of the above options.

```
struct Object
{
   explicit Object(int in) {}
   Object& operator=(int in) = delete;
};
```

#### Option 3:

If you don't want any assignment after initialization, you can `delete` the assignment operator with `Object` as argument type.

```
struct Object
{
   explicit Object(int in) {}
   Object& operator=(Object const& in) = delete;
};
```

That will prevent use of:

```
Object a(1);
a = Object(2); // Error
a = 2;         // Error
```

Answer (score 7):

Deleted functions are available only from C++11 onwards, for older compilers you can make the assignment operator `private`.

```
struct Object
{
Object(int) {}
private: 
Object& operator=(int);
};
```

Compiler will now throw error for

```
Object a=1; //ok
a=2; // error
```

But you can still do

```
Object a=1,b=2;
b=a;
```

Because the default assignment operator is not prevented from being generated by the compiler. So marking default assignment `private` will solve this issue.

```
struct Object
{
Object(int) {}
private: 
Object& operator=(Object&);
};
```