# How to get around objects that are restricted from assigning?

Tags: c++, qt

This is in response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41975114/objects-that-can-be-initialized-but-not-assigned).

QT does this (specifically, overriding the assignment operator to `delete`) for their QObjects. However, I need to assign QtGuiApplication to a global variable (I'm writing the application in C, with a QT wrapper in C++, which is why I can't call it directly in my main program). If I initialize it before, then it works, but only until the program ends (then it crashes).

So, I need to assign a value QT specifically does not want me to assign.

Comment: Allocate your object on the heap and return a pointer to your C application.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Yeah, I just figured that out just before you answered.

Comment: Are you aware of the `qApp` macro? Or `QCoreApplication::instance()` static method?

Comment: Qt does this deliberately, for several reasons, primarily so that owners of signals and slots don't get confused. Tread carefully here; it isn't generally necessary to circumvent this.

Comment: @hyde I just need to save it, so it won't get destroyed when it goes out of scope. I already use `qGuiApp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around it by just setting the global variable to a pointer (e.g, `QGuiApplication *app; app=new QGuiApplication(1,"")`).

Comment: Smart pointer would even be better.

Comment: Why do you need the global variable?

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the `QApplication` in a `std::optional`:

```
namespace
{
std::optional<QApplication> g_application;
}

extern "C"
{

int CreateQtApplication(void** app)
{
    if (app == nullptr)
    {
        return 1; // cannot write to out var
    }
    if (g_application.has_value())
    {
        return 2; // already initialized
    }
    try
    {
        *app = static_cast<QGuiApplication*>(&g_application.emplace());
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        return 3; // error initializing QApplication
    }
    return 0;
}

int DestroyQtApplication(void* app)
{
    if (!g_application.has_value() || (app != static_cast<QGuiApplication*>(&g_application.value())))
    {
        return 2; // invalid application passed
    }
    g_application.reset();
    return 0;
}

} // extern "C"

...

int main()
{
    void* guiApplication;
    int err = CreateQtApplication(&guiApplication);
    assert(err == 0);

    ...

    err = DestroyQtApplication(guiApplication);
    assert(err == 0);
}
```

Of course having a global you may not need to work with a pointer to the C functions...